# what are the Steps to setup nginx-clojure on windows 8

Tags: nginx, clojure

Steps followed to setup  nginx-clojure.0.4.0 in Windows-8 64 bit

1. Downloaded the nginx-clojure.0.4.0.tar
2. Unzipped the tar file  and named it as nginx
3. Modified the following properties in conf file

   ```
    nginx.conf :
        pid        logs/nginx.pid;  
        jvm_path "C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.7.0_17/jre/bin/server/jvm.dll";
        jvm_var my_other_jars 'D:/Learning/clojure-1.7.0/clojure-1.7.0.jar';
        jvm_options "-Djava.class.path=jars/nginx-clojure-0.4.0.jar:#{my_other_jars}";
        jvm_options "-Xms1024m";
        jvm_options "-Xmx1024m";
   ```
4. Started the server using command "nginx-win64.exe".Server start up is failing with following error

   - can not initialize jvm for load dynamic lib, maybe wrong jvm_path!
   - The system cannot find the file specified(logs/nginx.pid).

Please let me know if i need to modify any other parameters. I tried nginx-clojure.0.4.0 in mac book also to setup but failed.I tried nginx-clojure.0.3.0 also in windows 8 i failed

Answer (score 2):

The issue is you use a 32-bit JDK with a 64-bit Nginx-Clojure.
On 64-bit Windows-8  32-bit program will be installed to "C:/Program Files (x86)/".
So please try either of

1. install 64-bit JDK  OR
2. use nginx-win32.exe with 32-bit JDK

BTW if you want to use Nginx-Clojure on Macosx please try Nginx-Clojure 0.4.1 which can auto detect jvm path. e.g.

in nginx.conf

```
jvm_path auto;
```

**UPDATE:**

Your classpath is also wrong. On windows classpath seperator is `;`, not `:` . So Your classpath should be

```
jvm_options "-Djava.class.path=jars/nginx-clojure-0.4.0.jar;#{my_other_jars}";
```

Comment: i updated the jvm-path as jvm_path "C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_67/jre/bin/server/jvm.dll"; and am getting following error  **A)**.java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: nginx/clojure/MiniConstants **B)**.jvm may be mad for wrong options! See hs_err_pid****.log for detail! restarted 3. **C)** CreateFile() "D:\xyzabc\nginx/logs/nginx.pid" failed (2: The system cannot find the file specified) @xfeep

Comment: please check my updated answer for wrong classpath seperator. We should use `;` instead of `:`  on windows.

Comment: Please also remove `location /groovy { .. } `  because there's no groovy runtime jar.

Comment: Thanks. I removed groovy code and updated ; with ; in classpath separator.Am able to launch the localhost:8080/cojure successfully in browser. I will try in mac also. I have a question why we are using twice jvm_options "-Xms1024m";

Comment: They are different.  -Xm`s`1024m and -Xm`x`1024m,  the first sets the initial jvm heap size and the second sets the maximum jvm heap size.

Comment: BTW, since 0.4.1 nginx-clojure provides embedding APIs to make test/debug at dev phase be more easier. Please see http://nginx-clojure.github.io/embed.html .